ESP32 LEDC not reading correct ADC register
What I've done is implemented two different PWM signals with different frequencies, Freq.1 = 11 bit number and Freq.2 = 15 bit.
What I expect out of my while statement is the register of the 15 bit number being that I'm pointing to it. However, what I get is my 11 bit number and even that is starts it's reading value from 0 and not it's current value.
ledc_timer_config_t ledc_timer_A = {
    .duty_resolution = LEDC_TIMER_11_BIT,
    .freq_hz = 20000,
    .speed_mode = LEDC_HS_MODE,
    .timer_num = LEDC_TIMER_0,
    .clk_cfg = LEDC_AUTO_CLK,
};
ledc_timer_config_t ledc_timer_D = {
    .duty_resolution = LEDC_TIMER_15_BIT,
    .freq_hz = 1250,                     
    .speed_mode = LEDC_HS_MODE,          
    .timer_num = LEDC_TIMER_1,          
    .clk_cfg = LEDC_USE_APB_CLK,              
};
ledc_timer_config(&ledc_timer_A);
ledc_timer_config(&ledc_timer_D);
ledc_channel_config_t ledc_channel[2] = {
    {
        .channel    = LEDC_HS_CH0_CHANNEL,
        .duty       = 0,
        .gpio_num   = LEDC_HS_CH0_GPIO,
        .speed_mode = LEDC_HS_MODE,
        .hpoint     = 0,
        .timer_sel  = LEDC_HS_TIMER,
        .flags.output_invert = 0
    },
    {
        .channel    = LEDC_HS_CH1_CHANNEL,
        .duty       = 0,
        .gpio_num   = LEDC_HS_CH1_GPIO,
        .speed_mode = LEDC_HS_MODE,
        .hpoint     = 0,
        .timer_sel  = LEDC_HS_TIMER_2,
        .flags.output_invert = 0
    },
}; 

ledc_channel_config(&ledc_channel[0]);
ledc_channel_config(&ledc_channel[1]);

int PWM_primary = map_analog(65);
ledc_set_duty(ledc_channel[0].speed_mode, ledc_channel[0].channel, PWM_primary);
ledc_update_duty(ledc_channel[0].speed_mode, ledc_channel[0].channel);
vTaskDelay(50/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

//Secondary pwm signal
PWM_Secondary_Time = ((65.0 - (float)Duty_cycle_prev)/abs((float)Duty_cycle_prev - (float)Duty_cycle)) * Total_Time;
    int PWM_Secondary = map_secondary(65);
ledc_set_fade_with_time(LEDC_HIGH_SPEED_MODE,
    LEDC_CHANNEL_1, PWM_Secondary, PWM_Secondary_Time);
ledc_fade_start(LEDC_HIGH_SPEED_MODE,
    LEDC_CHANNEL_1, LEDC_FADE_NO_WAIT);

vTaskDelay(PWM_Secondary_Time/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
while(secondary_Pres_Dc != 160){
    secondary_Pres_Dc =  ledc_get_duty(ledc_channel[1].speed_mode,ledc_channel[1].channel);
    printf("%lu\n",secondary_Pres_Dc);
    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //100ms
}

//PWM_primary
PWM_primary = map_primary(Duty_cycle);
PWM_primary_Time = (((float)Duty_cycle - 65.0)/abs((float)Duty_cycle_prev - (float)Duty_cycle)) * Total_Time;
ledc_set_fade_with_time(LEDC_HIGH_SPEED_MODE,
    LEDC_CHANNEL_0, PWM_primary, PWM_primary_Time);
ledc_fade_start(LEDC_HIGH_SPEED_MODE,
    LEDC_CHANNEL_0, LEDC_FADE_NO_WAIT);

the above is what I've tried and so far no luck with it.
EDIT:
The core of my question here is why, when the printing secondary_pres_DC, do I see the primary_pres_DC instead. Even when it isn't requesting the 'primary' value
Added in code for the assignment for timers

I'm confused, your title and tags refer to reading an ADC, but your question body seems to be about PWM. It's also not clear to be what the problem you have is, and where these "15-bit" and "11-bit" numbers are used and expected.

@ThomasJager I've added in an edit and hopefully that solves that issue. Basically my question is when reading a value in 'PWM register B', why do I see 'PWM register A'?

The title bares no relationship to the question or the code.  LEDC appears to be a name you chose for symbols in your code, the title refers to it but out of context it has no relevance.  There is no ADC register in this code, and not mentioned in the question.

I suggest you edit the question so it makes sense rather than adding further information - or asking the same thing in a different way.

@Clifford A web search brings up those ledc_* functions as being part of the SDK for this MCU.

@ThomasJager  yes I just spotted that.  But it is still largely irrelevant to the question.

It would be far clear if your question referred to the specific lines of code and symbols in that code.  There is no Freq.1 for example, it could be clear what you were referring to.

@Raiser Adding in the extra information doesn't really clarify the problem. You've left "ADC" in the title, even though nothing shown uses an ADC. The use of LEDC_HS_TIMER and LEDC_HS_TIMER_2 is a bit suspicious. I don't know what you've defined those to be, but I'd double-check that the actually have the values that you think they do, and don't point to the same time.

As @ThomasJager points out, ledc_channel_config_t.timer_sel
is enum ledc_timer_t (see here)  Neither LEDC_HS_TIMER_2 nor LEDC_HS_TIMER are enumerations of that type.

I think the channel timer_sel needs to match the timer timer_num.  That seems to be the only way the timer and the channel are associated in this frankly abysmal interface.  They are after all of the same type.
